# Can not edit font on drawing tool

Tags: text, drawing

I am simply trying to add some text to a plot via the drawing tool, but it seems the text style options are fixed at some default setting and will not change. You can see in the following picture that I have set totally wild text settings, but they do not show in the text I just entered. Any help?

I am using v.11.2.0 for Linux x86.

[image]

Comment: On second try, you are right. I was only able to change the setting *once*, and now the text size is "stuck" at the first size I selected, no matter what I do. Indeed, this seems a bug of sorts, at least in v. 11.2. (I owe you an upvote; I'm out for the day!)

Comment: I have experienced serious problems with  the drawing tool under Mathematica 11.2. Here is the text of my bug report :"Bug with Drawing Tool on Mathematica 11.2 windows 7 64bits Trial Version : Once you have entered some text in the "keep" mode (double click on the Button T), you can't leave the mode "text writing", that is to say you can't do anything else on the graphic (for example draw a circle). This problem doesn't exist with the traditional text button (the one with a Sigma). " Case:3957686. For this reason, I decided not to buy 11.2. Now, with 11.3 no more problems.

Comment: I had the answer from WR : "A workaround is to click in the notebook outside the graphic.". I'm pretty sure that didn't work in my case  (I couldn't verify because my trial version had reach the time-out).

Comment: The version 11.0 doesn't have problem either.

Comment: 11.2 the workaround absolutely does not work.  In fact, you can select another graphic, move out of Text mode (clearly shown on drawing tools palette) but the choice reverts to Text in the original graphic.  Of course, there are keyboard shortcuts to move to another mode.  Only thing is, as you are already in Text mode, they will be inserted at cursor position as text rather than changing edit mode.  And I can't easily get to 11.3...

Comment: Problem persists on Mac V 12.0.0

Comment: I typically add text to graphics programmatically. For many reasons, it is much better, than to do it with the drawing tool. If you post your code and explain what text you need to add I could show the way.

Answer (score 1):

after you're done inserting the text, select the text by clicking it (text will be surrounded by resizable orange frame), you can use Alt-minus and Alt-plus to make the text smaller or bigger.

Comment: I don't think this answers the OPs actual question...

Comment: Works. Thanks..